# Opening dialog on showing sap.m.Page

Tags: sapui5

Having some trouble opening a Dialog after navigating to a page. The intention is to always open the dialog when a user lands on this page.

Simplified, I have a controller that looks like this:

```
onInit: function() {}
  this.myRouter.getRoute("orderscreate").attachPatternMatched(this._onObjectMatched, this);
},

_onObjectMatched: function() {
  this.dialog = sap.ui.xmlfragment("myDialog", this);
  this.dialog.open();
},
```

When I put a debugger in, this works great: I can see the dialog is open.

THEN, the navigation animation kicks in, does the slide animation, and upon completion the dialog is closed again. I'm not sure why it insist on navigating after the view has rendered.

This happens when using `navTo` as well. Dialog opens, animation starts, dialog is closed again. `sap.m.Page` does not have another way of executing code after showing, as far as I'm aware.

Any advice?

Comment: You could try the [`display`](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.core.routing.Target.html#attachDisplay) event of the Target instead of `patternMatched`.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless told otherwise the TargetHandler will close all open dialogs.

> TargetHandler, a class used for closing dialogs and showing transitions in NavContainers when targets are displayed.

Try adding the following code after your router has been initialized

```
this.myRouter.getTargetHandler().setCloseDialogs(false);
```